# The base64 encode formatted output from Arduino HMAC-SHA1 does not match with JAVA/python/online tool

Tags: twitter, oauth, arduino

I am working on an Arduino project which is required an authorized authentication based on OAuth 1.0 to connects to the cloud. This is alike [Authorizing a request to Twitter API][1], and I am stuck in the step of [Creating a signature][2]. The whole process of creating a signature requires algorithms like encodeURL, base64encode, and hmac-sha1. On my Arduino project, I use Cryptosuite(link 3) library for hmac-sha1 and arduino-base64(link 4) library for base64encode. Both of them are working fine separately. However, I need to get a base64-formatted output of hmac-sha1. So I have tried this:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <sha1.h>
#include <Base64.h>

uint8_t *in, out, i;
char b64[29];
static const char PROGMEM b64chars[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
char key[] = "testKey";
char basestring[] = "testing";


void printHash(uint8_t* hash) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]>>4]);
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]&0xf]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Result:");
  Sha1.initHmac((uint8_t*)key, strlen(key));
  Sha1.print(basestring);
  printHash(Sha1.resultHmac());
  Serial.println();

  // encoding
  char* input;
  input = (char*)(Sha1.resultHmac());
  int inputLen = strlen(input);
  int encodedLen = base64_enc_len(inputLen);
  char encoded[encodedLen];

  // note input is consumed in this step: it will be empty afterwards
  base64_encode(encoded, input, inputLen); 

  Serial.print("base64 result: ");
  Serial.println(encoded);

}

void loop() {
}
```

The output of printHash that I got is 60d41271d43b875b791e2d54c34bf3f018a29763, which is exactly same with the online verification tool(link 5).
However, I supposed to get YNQScdQ7h1t5Hi1Uw0vz8Biil2M= for the base64 result. But I got L18B0HicKRhuxmB6SIFpZP+DpHxU which seems wrong. I have also tried to write a JAVA program and a python program, which also said that the output of the base64 result should be YNQScdQ7h1t5Hi1Uw0vz8Biil2M=

I also found this post: Issues talking between Arduino SHA1-HMAC and base64 encoding and Python(link 6). I have also tried the tidy function it mentioned from Adafruit-Tweet-Receipt(link 7).

```
  // base64-encode SHA-1 hash output.  This is NOT a general-purpose base64
  // encoder!  It's stripped down for the fixed-length hash -- always 20
  // bytes input, always 27 chars output + '='.
  for(in = Sha1.resultHmac(), out=0; ; in += 3) { // octets to sextets
    b64[out++] =   in[0] >> 2;
    b64[out++] = ((in[0] & 0x03) << 4) | (in[1] >> 4);
    if(out >= 26) break;
    b64[out++] = ((in[1] & 0x0f) << 2) | (in[2] >> 6);
    b64[out++] =   in[2] & 0x3f;
  }
  b64[out] = (in[1] & 0x0f) << 2;
  // Remap sextets to base64 ASCII chars
  for(i=0; i<=out; i++) b64[i] = pgm_read_byte(&b64chars[b64[i]]);
  b64[i++] = '=';
  b64[i++] = 0;
```

Is there any mistake I've made in here?
Thanks!

Comment: False alarm, I tried to access Sha1.resultHmac() twice. That makes the sha result different.

Answer (score 0):

So full example will be:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <sha1.h>
#include <Base64.h>

char key[] = "testKey";
char basestring[] = "testing";

void printHash(uint8_t* hash) {  
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]>>4]);
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]&0xf]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Input:              ");
  Serial.println(basestring);

  Serial.print("Key:                ");
  Serial.println(key);

  Serial.print("Hmac-sha1 (hex):    ");
  Sha1.initHmac((uint8_t*)key, strlen(key));
  Sha1.print(basestring);

  uint8_t *hash;
  hash = Sha1.resultHmac();
  printHash(hash);

  // base64 encoding
  char* input = (char*) hash;
  int inputLen = strlen(input) - 1; // skip null termination

  int encodedLen = base64_enc_len(inputLen);
  char encoded[encodedLen];

  // note input is consumed in this step: it will be empty afterwards
  base64_encode(encoded, input, inputLen); 
  Serial.print("Hmac-sha1 (base64): ");
  Serial.println(encoded);
}

void loop() { }
```

which outputs:

```
Input:              testing
Key:                testKey
Hmac-sha1 (hex):    60d41271d43b875b791e2d54c34bf3f018a29763
Hmac-sha1 (base64): YNQScdQ7h1t5Hi1Uw0vz8Biil2M=
```